# EditText color changing with keyboard input

Tags: android

I have set the android:textColor attribute of an EditText control to blue and sure enough when 
text is added via append() the text is blue. However it changes to black when entering from the keyboard. I have also set android:textColorHighlight to blue but still have the same issue of it going black when keyboard is used.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: provide your xml that contains EditText

Comment: It could be the auto-correcting. When you type a lot, does it stay black?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an `AutoCompleteTextView`. I found removing this from my xml fixed the problem.

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

With out seeing your xml I have no idea if this will help, but I hope it will help others.